# Setting GIF loop count and publishing stop event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is it possible to set the loop count of a GIF image using JavaScript and then publish an event when it stops playing?

For example something like:

```
//html code
<img src="myImage.gif" id="img1"/>

//Javascript code
var image = document.getElementById('img1');

//Image must stop playing after 3 loops
image.setLoopCount = 3;
```

Comment: The answer is _"No, not using JavaScript and an actual animated GIF"._ All the answers so far are helping you with alternatives, but are forgetting to provide this fundamental answer.

Answer (score 3):

here is how i would suggest doing it:

- extract frames form gif file (you can do it online using for instace -> http://imgops.com/)
- use javascript to change pictures, simulating animation (that way you can keep track of how many loops you have done)

Here is a jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/qustosh/n5zWH/9/
I used jQuery. I did three loops and i threw a callback function at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For a design side solution, you can set the GIF image to only loop a certain number of times with Photoshop. Then just use `window.setTimeout(callback, milliseconds)` to trigger your custom event.

You can calculate the time out from the interval used to display each frame of the animation.